# How do I check if 2 databases are opened or closed (one in sqlite3 and the other in MySQL) - Python 3.3?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite

I have opened 2 databases, one in mysql (using mysql connector for Python) and another one in sqlite3 (using the standar sqlite3 module). My code requires that I constantly open and close the connections, but I don't know how to check if the connection is already open or closed. The documentation for MySQL says that there is an .open attribute that tells me so, but Python gives me an error when I try it. Also, can't I just do this:

```
connection1.close()
connection2.close()

if connection1.closed == True:
    connection1.open()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: One vague idea is to try to use the cursor for something, then catch the error it raises if its closed, then reopen it in that error catch.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysql connector python,
you can use `is_connected()` method of the connection object which returns
`True` if the connection is still active and `False` otherwise.